# Считыванние данных из файла

Tags: c++, qt, файлы, qt5

Как можно считать данные с

```
QFile f("file.txt", QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

В файле данные записаны в таком формате

> Str1 Str2 Str3

И нужно считать данные, записать их в переменные str1, str2, str3?

Через fstream это выглядело бы так:

```
fstream f;
while(f)
{
    f >> str1 >> str2 >> str3;
}
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfile.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать также как у вас, но при помощи инструментов Qt:

```
QFile file("file.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return 0;

QTextStream in(&file);
QString str1, str2, str3;

while (!in.atEnd()) {
    in >> str1 >> str2 >> str3;
}

qDebug() << str1 << str2 << str3; // Выведет Str1 Str2 Str3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
QFile f("file.txt", QIODevice::ReadOnly); 
QStringList strings; // сюда будут получены слова
if(f.open()){ // открываете файл
    QByteArray data = f.readAll(); // Читаете все из файла
    strings = QString(data).split(" "); // разбиваете по пробелу на слова  
}
```